# Does their exist a restriction of a bounded linear operator on an infinite dimensional subspace which is compact?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let T be a bounded linear operator from a **norm space X** to a **Banach space Y**, can the restriction of T to an infinite dimensional subspace of X be compact or not?
If Yes, then How?
Please explain the answer.

Comment: $0$ is a compact operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is if there always exists such a restriction then the answer is no. It is a known fact that the identity operator on infinite dimensional spaces is not compact. So if you restrict the identity operator $Id:X\to X$ to any subspace with infinite dimension it will not be compact.

**Edit:** it is possible for a restriction of a non compact operator to be compact. Take $X=l^2$, the space of all complex sequences $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^2<\infty$. This is a Banach space. Define $T:X\to X$ by $T(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)=(0,x_1,0,x_3,0,x_5,...)$. This operator is not compact, it is easy to check. (think about the vectors of the standard basis to show it is not compact). But if you restrict it to the subspace of vectors in $l^2$ with zeros in all of the coordinates with even index (which is obviously an infinite dimensional subspace) then $T$ will become the zero operator, hence compact.

Comment: not always my question, Is there any operator exist whose restriction is compact but the operator itself is not compact.

Comment: Alright, I edited my answer.